# Update database table once asyncio co-routine is complete

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to do the following

1. Insert a database record to indicate a job is running
2. Kick off an asyncio routine
3. Update the database table once the routine is complete

This is my current code:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
conn = db.cursor()
insert_query = f"""INSERT INTO batch_jobs
                          (job_name, user_id, status, type) 
                           VALUES 
                          ('{job}','{user_id}','Running','clause_extract')"""

conn.execute(insert_query)
db.commit()
db.close()
print("Record inserted successfully into batch_job table ", conn.rowcount)
row_id = conn.lastrowid

# This is my async job
output = asyncio.run(aall_answers_all_docs(doc_list, template))
    
    
update_query = f"""UPDATE batch_jobs 
                       SET status = 'Finished',
                           file_location = './data/csv_files/{file_name}'
                       WHERE id = {row_id}"""
    
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
conn = db.cursor()
conn.execute(update_query)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

However I get an error `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`

I'm assuming that multiple tasks are trying to write to the db to the same time. So how can I wait until the whole asyncio job is finished and my output is delivered. I tried asyncio.gather but that didn't work

Comment: Full relevant code and traceback please.

Comment: `aiosqlite` maybe help you. This package build for async function